# Вернуть все результаты из замыкания Laravel

Tags: laravel, foreach

В контроллере есть метод, со следующим кодом:

```
    $tenders = Tender::where('user_id', '=', $id)->
        groupBy('product_id')->
            orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();

    $products = $tenders->pipe(function($tenders){
        foreach ($tenders as $tender){
             return Product::where('id', '=', $tender->product_id)->get();
        }
    });

    return view('product', compact('products'));
```

Выводится только 1 элемент коллекции, на самом деле их 3. Предполагаю, что проблема в foreach. Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в `pipe` я так полагаю. Вам нужно использовать метод `map`:

```
$products = $tenders->map(function($tender){
    return Product::where('id', '=', $tender->product_id)->first();
});
```

Но ещё лучше через реляцию брать эти данные, если они у вас описаны то должно быть что-то типо такого:

```
$tenders = Tender::with('product')
                ->where('user_id', '=', $id)
                ->groupBy('product_id')
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                ->get();
$products = $tenders->map(function($tender){
    return $tender->product;
});
```